# Gradient of an absolute value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What is the gradient of $|\vec{x}|^2$?

Is it simply $2\vec{x}$, or does the answer get expressed using absolute value notation?

Comment: How many dimensions are there in the vector $\vec x$? Also, derivatives of vectors are usually with respect to $t$ (time) and sometimes $s$ (arc length), but rarely $x$. Is that what you mean? Using the same variable ($x$) for the dependent and the independent variable is confusing.

Comment: Originally, the question was about taking the derivative of a Hamiltonian given by $H(\vec{p}, \vec{x}) = \frac{|\vec{p}|^2}{2m} - V(\vec{x})$.

Comment: I don't know how many dimensions I am working in. Should that matter?

Comment: A one-dimensional vector would be simple here, as in $\frac d{dx}|x|$. With higher dimensions the same variable $x$ is confusing.

Comment: Is the $x$ iin $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ the same as $\vec{x}$. If so, how do you define $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ if $\vec{x}$ is a vector?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(x) = \|x\|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$. Then
$\phi(x+h)-\phi(x) = 2 x^T h + \|h\|^2$, and so we see
that $D \phi(x) = 2 x^T$, or, if you prefer, $\nabla \phi(x) = 2x$.

Comment: That answers my question, thank you.

Comment: By the way, does this match up with the idea that $\frac{d}{du}|u| = \frac{uu'}{|u|}$?

Comment: This would be the chain rule applied to the composition of $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ and $u \mapsto \|u\|^2$. I'm note sure what you mean by $u'$, I presume this would be the identity map.

Comment: Please tell me why this was downvoted?